# How can I tell who are major investors in an asset management group and their associated funds?

Tags: stock-market, investment

I am trying to determine which individuals/organizations are the largest investors in Netflix, but when I look at the list of top shareholders, they are all investment management groups.  Investment management groups are  not investing their own money, they are investing the money of others, usually through investments in their associated funds.   Is there any way of seeing who are the major investors in investment groups or their associated funds?

Comment: The answer probably is that you cannot. In any event, this question might better be asked on the Quantitative Finance stack exchange.

Comment: Brian is right, you generally can’t. And most of the top shareholders are most likely retail index mutual funds, so their ultimate owners are just ordinary people, through their retirement accounts. It’s generally the non-mutual fund shareholders that are interesting (and you can’t know their shareholders unless those people or entities have to file disclosures for some reason).